# Getting SCRIPT5022: SecurityError in zone.js (192,25)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, zonejs

I'm getting `SCRIPT5022: SecurityError in zone.js (192,25)` intermittently when I load an Angular component in an iframe on IE11.

Other than that the frame is working and I don't notice anything broken.

This is the code around the error:

```
            try {
                return this._zoneDelegate.invokeTask(this, task, applyThis, applyArgs);
            }
            catch (error) {
                if (this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, error)) {
line 192:           throw error;
                }
            }
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error? I've also found this issue on github which looks the same - https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using [uberspeck's solution](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1001#issuecomment-439637375) of adding the below 2 lines of code to my polyfills.ts file.

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add this script in index.html

```
<script>
  __Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
</script>
```